# Using libpcap.dylib on a kext

Tags: macos, pcap, kernel-extension

I am writing a kext driver for OS X and would like to use functions from the library `libpcap.dylib`. Libpcap.dylib lives in /usr/lib on OS X. Can it be used from kernel space? How can I use libpcap.dylib from a kext using Xcode?

I manage to compile -- (-lpcap apears as link option) but:

- got an warning on `"unexpected dylib"` by linker. It is clear that is misplaced somehow.
- kextload can't resolve libpcap dependencies.
- kextlibs shows only libs that I include thru OsBundleLibraries suggesting that my dylib is ignored.

I am aware of similar question [Linking Dylibs in Kexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189397/linking-dylibs-in-kexts) but want to know if someone have have used libpcap on a kext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinPcap has both user-land and kernel-mode components, because the Windows kernels don't provide the necessary kernel-mode components.

On UN*X systems - for example, on OS X - the kernel-mode components are part of the OS, and libpcap only includes user-mode code.

The equivalent, in *BSD and OS X, of WinPcap's kernel-mode code is BPF, which you won't be able to use from a kext.  In addition, BPF has no equivalent of the send-queue stuff to do synchronized transmission of packets - you can send packets, but that just immediately injects the packet into the network stack - so neither using libpcap from your kext, nor using raw BPF from your kext, would help you with your timing needs.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation on libpcap highlighting differences between SO's.
I am doing some research on Interface Filters and Internet Protocol filters -- those should be used at least for receive audio from Ethernet as I think of doing through libpcap.
After this the "missing part" will be access network device to send packets with my timing needs... But the mentioned part will keep me busy for a while. :)

Comment: @mano2a0c40 You can open sockets (TCP, UDP) from within the kernel, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As is noted in [Linking Dylibs in Kexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189397/linking-dylibs-in-kexts), it's not possible to load a dylib in to the kernel via a kernel extension.

You don't mention what it is you're trying to achieve so it's difficult to know what alternatives would be relevant to you. I'd suggest reading up on [Network Kernel Extensions][1] to see if one of the techniques they cover could be used instead of pcap. Alternatively, you could make use of pcap from a userspace program and communicate with it from your kernel extension.

Comment: I have used WinPcap on windows to do basic filtering (I think I can do it "manually" on MACOSX) and sending packets through a queue. I use pcap_send_queue because of my tight timing needs.
On MACOSX it will be an coreaudio driver that should transmit packets with raw audio data over Ethernet every 500microsseconds. I look at pcap just because it is easier to work with known tecnology... Thanks for pointing NKE;